# Excel 2003 to 2013 - OLAP issue

Tags: sql-server, excel, pivot-table, olap, vba

We have some very old 2003 workbooks designed by someone who has now left this dept. We need to convert them to Excel 2013, but when we open them and refresh the pivot tables it comes up with a wizard asking for a data source?

The pivot tables are linked to specific 'Connections' for each table. I've looked at these, and the connections seem to be 'OLAP queries', one of them is below :-

```
Provider=MSOLAP.5;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=OCWCube;Extended Properties="Client Cache Size=25";Auto Synch Period=10000;

CREATECUBE=CREATE CUBE [OCWCube] (   DIMENSION [Target],    LEVEL [All] TYPE ALL,    LEVEL [Target],   DIMENSION [WeekCommencing],    LEVEL [All] TYPE ALL,    LEVEL [WeekCommencing],   DIMENSION [DocType],    LEVEL [All] TYPE ALL,    LEVEL [DocType],   DIMENSION [Team],    LEVEL [All] TYPE ALL,    LEVEL [Team],   MEASURE [Sum Of CountGuid]    FUNCTION SUM  );

INSERTINTO=INSERT INTO OCWCube([Team].[Team], [DocType].[DocType], [Sum Of CountGuid], [WeekCommencing].[WeekCommencing], [Target].[Target])  OPTIONS ATTEMPT_DEFER, ATTEMPT_ANALYSIS  SELECT BenOpsWorkOverdue.Team, BenOpsWorkOverdue.DocType, BenOpsWorkOverdue.CountGuid, BenOpsWorkOverdue.WeekCommencing, BenOpsWorkOverdue.Target  FROM SysAdminStats.dbo.BenOpsWorkOverdue BenOpsWorkOverdue;

MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;
SOURCE_DSN="DSN=SysAdminStats;
Description=System Admin Stats;
UID=xxxxx;
APP=Microsoft Office 2003;
WSID=MCC001T117;
DATABASE=SysAdminStats;Trusted_Connection=Yes";
MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;
Update Isolation Level=2
```

The UID value is the the AD login of the person who designed the workbooks, he is still active in AD but works in another dept.

I don't know why there designed like this. As I understand it, the SystemsAdminStats database is an SQL server database, and BenOpsWorkOverdue is a table on that database. I think the WSID is the machine name of the SQL Server instance that the DB sits on, but I am not 100%.

I think this OLAP query is just selecting certain fields from that SQL Server table for Pivot Table. Each pivot table in the workbook has a different connection with a different OLAP query.

How can I get these working in Excel 2013? I thinkt he problem is that we want the pivot table linked to the results of an SQL on the table, rather than just to the table itself, hence why it was done like this? I'm not 100% sure.

Surely there should be an easier way of connecting a pivottable to the results of an SQL in Excel than using these OLAP connections?

Comment: I converted to Excel 2013 format (maro-enabled), if I try and "re-do" the connection by selecting the table and changing data source, and reselecting the same connection, I get an error 'Errors in the OLE DB provider...The data source or location is not valid. Please provide server to which to connect"

Comment: Data source is the server name which is missing here. Initial Catalog is the Analysis Services database name since your provide is MSOLAP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services

Comment: I've added Data Source and same thing happens. It thrown an error when refreshing the pivit and then brings up a wizard called 'multi dimensional connection 11.00; which is asking for a server name, when I input the server name MCC001T117 (which is what the WSID is set to in the query), it cannot detect it.

Also, this doesn't explain how it works perfectly fine in Excel 2003 (although this runs in different Citrix servers).

I don't know much about cubes/OLAP which isn't helping.

Comment: I don't think MCC001T117 is your server name. You need server name for cube OCWCube.